# how can i lower my hdri lighting strength

Tags: lighting, hdri, world

how can I lower my hdri lighting strength to almost 0? I'm making a 1 shot timelapse style from daytime to night fall in one shot. I attached my shader web for my world shader.

[image]

Comment: Turn down the Background node value from 1.2 down to 0. You can keyframe this if you want to transition from 0 to something bright. Hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: thank you @tester